# 16.04 Delete key not working

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

I noticed I cannot delete with the delete key, which was working fine in win 10. However, shift + del does the same thing.

Is there a way i can map it to del instead? i checked shortcuts in keyboard, but the option wasn't there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I chanced upon an article that explains this clearly. For new Ubuntu users, in win 10 your delete key moves your item to recycle bin. In Ubuntu, the equivalent is **ctrl+del**. To change this to using del only, follow the instructions at this link.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/08/restore-delete-key-for-moving-files-to.html

In essence, it's:

1) In terminal type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface can-change-accels true
```

2) Open any Nautilus window (your normal GUI interface) of any file, right click any folder or file, hover over the move to trash and press del twice to reassign del to this.