# Delete key or dragging a file to Trash doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, nautilus, delete, trash

I am new to Ubuntu and using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. For some reason the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key or dragging a file to trash is not working. Pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> key doesn't do anything. And dragging a file to the trash shows:

**'filename' can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?"**

I have already tried the solutions mentioned in:

- ["Move to trash" not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829785/move-to-trash-not-working)
- [16.04 Delete key not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778664/16-04-delete-key-not-working)
- [Can't move files to the trash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288513/cant-move-files-to-the-trash)

but they don't work.

P.S. I am able to use the delete key or dragging a file to Trash, under the root directory but on any other partition, the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key or dragging to trash doesn't work. However, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is working fine to delete files permanently.

Comment: Are you working with files on a network drive?

Comment: @OrganicMarble No network drive, I am talking about local partitions. On my SSD, I have my root and one more partition. And I have an HDD too. Del key works only under the root directory. Earlier it used to work everywhere and I was able to delete files (move to Trash and not permanent delete), but I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: @OrganicMarble still not able to fix this. Did you get a chance to look further into it?